# Why Hibernate now uses TABLE strategy as default for MySQL?

Tags: hibernate, primary-key

Why did Hibernate changed the AUTO generation strategy for IDs in MySql to TABLE?
Is there any clear advantage using this strategy in MySQL? It is for portability of code across different databases?

In Hibernate's Git repo [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc#id-sequence-defaults) and [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc#id-sequence-defaults) you can find some maybe correlated explanations.

On top of that I stumbled upon this [Hibernate forum question](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/generated-value-strategy-auto/6481/2) that says:

> Generally, a table based sequence strategy is the most efficient strategy you can use on MySQL which lacks support for native sequences. The performance advantage of this approach is visible when you use a proper allocation size for the sequence i.e. 50+

Have you experienced such improved efficinecy ?